# How to query two tables by two matching fields but only display results with one match?

Tags: mysql

The following query below displays rows from table1 and table2 in which fields Mascot + Zip match.  Great!   The problem is this may return multiple matches and possible false positives.  To avoid this, I only want the query to return a result if there is only 1 match.  My code below will return the Tigers:47483 row.  If there is more than 1 match, I do not want anything returned.  How do I set up this restriction?

```
Sports1 Table
id    School    Mascot    Zip
1     West      Tigers    47483
2     Central   Trojans   38493
3     Stone     Eagles    38493

Sports2 Table
id    School    Mascot    Zip
1     West      Tigers    47483
2     Central   Trojans   38493
3     Stone     Eagles    38493
4     South     Tigers    47483


SELECT t1.*
FROM Sports1 t1, Sports2 t2
WHERE (t1.Mascot = t2.Mascot AND t1.Zip = t2.Zip) GROUP by t1.id;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your query should currently be returning multiple rows, because there are other rows that match on Mascot and Zip as well

Comment: Yes, but if there are multiple rows, I do not want the result returned.

Comment: Also, do you want it to return nothing if the query results in more than one row in general? Or more than one record for a given Mascot-Zip pair? (such as what happens with your current example with the two different schools that both have Tigers & 47483)

Comment: What is the application of the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Currently, West:Tigers:47483 and South:Tigers:47483 are returned.  I do not want either row retruned since there are 2 matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similiar answer as John,

```
SELECT *,count(*) FROM sports1 t1
JOIN  sports2 t2 ON (t1.Mascot=t2.Mascot AND t1.Zip=t2.Zip)
GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING count(*)=1;
```

For "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" error, run this :

```
SET sql_mode ='';
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT t1.Mascot,t1.Zip
FROM Sports1 t1, Sports2 t2
WHERE (t1.Mascot = t2.Mascot AND t1.Zip = t2.Zip) GROUP by t1.Mascot,t1.Zip 
 having count(DISTINCT t1.Mascot,t1.Zip)=1;

use this ,you can get only 1 match

Comment: I received this error message:  Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database_name.t1.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by